# Ruby on Rails 4, form inside a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, view

I am currently trying to build a view that shows a question to the user and if they answer the question right, allows the user to check a checkbox which sends a request to persist that in the database. In other words we keep track of what questions have been answered correctly by the user in the database. 
Now my issue is that (besides being a complete newbie in RoR and front end in general), I don't know how to insert the checkbox (form) inside my view along with the question.
I'm using rails 4.
Thank you!

Comment: You probably don't need a checkbox as such, any element like button will do the job...in other words you dont need to include another form element or form. are you talking about multiple choice questions ?? answering your question below with a small example.

Comment: Please add more details, like code snippet and use case..not sure if I am thinking in right way..don't want to assume things here

Comment: @Abhinay you might be right about the button... No it's not a multiple choice question, just a text field for questions and when the user wants, click to reveal the answer in another text field. If they got the question right, I want a way to record that and set the boolean value in the database to true to know which questions they answered correctly.

Comment: it would be nice to know more about what you are doing

Comment: Sure, it's very simple. I have 3 tables: fields, categories, quizzes. Quizzes has columns mentioned above. So the user can create a new quiz via a form (new quiz) by adding question, and answer and selecting the field and the category. Now in quizzes_controller, I have added a new method that allows users to see the questions, click to reveal the answer, and if they got the answer right, click or check a checkbox so I know which ones they got right and won't show them those questions again. What I can do is similar to editing a record but I don't want the answer and questions to be editable.

Answer (score 0):

I would start adding a Boolean value to all the answers.

```
$  rails g migration AddCorrectToAnswers
```

now that migration should look like

```
class AddCorrectToAnswers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :answers, :correct, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

now we can create a new route that will mark the answers correct

```
# config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  resources :questions do
    resources :answers do
     match "/correct" => "answers#correct", :as => :correct, via: :all
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Now you should have a new route

```
question_answer_correct        /questions/:question_id/answers/:answer_id/correct(.:format) answers#correct
```

I am assuming that the answer are in the questions show page

now in your show page you can do something like this

```
# app/views/questions/show.html.erb

<% @question.answers.each do |answer| %>
  <%= answer.answer %>
  <%= form_for @user, :url => url_for(:controller => 'answers', :action => 'correct') %>
    <%= f.label "Correct Answer" %> <br />
    <%= f.check_box :correct %> <br />
    ....
  <%end %>
<% end %>
```

Now the last thing you have to do is create a method in the answers controller called correct to mark the answers as correct

```
# app/controllers/answers_controller.rb
class AnswersControlle < ApplicationController
  ...
  def correct
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])
    @answer.correct = true
    @answer.save
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

I hope that this helps

Happy coding

Comment: The answer to the questions above and this solution, questions and answers are all in the same table. `class CreateQuizzes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :quizzes do |t|
      t.integer :field_id
      t.integer :category_id
      t.string :question
      t.string :answer
      t.timestamp :last
      t.boolean :was_correct

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have form setup,

you can add one button which says submit or anything you want to diplay

```
<button class="check">Click me</button>
```

Now you can write an event listener for this button which can reveal the answer and if it matches to the answer which User has given, then fire and Ajax call to your backend and save whatever you want to.

example code:

```
$('.check').on('click', function(){
  var real = $('.reveal-answer').val();
  $('.reveal-answer').show();   // you need to protect this part from being abused
  var answer = $('.user-input-answer').val();   //Assuming its a input field
 var questionId = $('.question').data('question-id');
 if(answer === real){
   url = '/submit_answer';
   data = { question_id: questionId, answer: answer };
   $.post( url, data , function() {
   }, 'json');
 }
});
```

Roughly it should work like this but there are lot to do from the security prospective. For ex: You can not have all answers on view side, You should do the backend validation once the answer is submitted(to check whether it is actually correct or someone tried to hack it.)

Comment: After this you can use another answer posted here for backend stuffs.